# Xcode 8 Playground doesn't display NSView

Tags: xcode, xcode8, swift-playground

Xcode doesn't display `NSView` in the playground. But it's displaying `UIView` without any problem. Is it a bug?

Code:

```
let view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Also the Xcode Playground is very slow. Is there any way to speed up the playground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIView` and `NSView` both are different in their workings. The code you posted is enough for `UIView` but not for `NSView`.

**According to Apple Documentation for [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview):**

> An NSView object provides the infrastructure for drawing, printing,
>   and handling events in an app. You typically don’t use NSView objects
>   directly. Instead, you use objects whose classes descend from NSView
>   or you subclass NSView yourself and override its methods to implement
>   the behavior you need.

**and**

> [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483686-draw) draws the NSView object. (All subclasses must implement this
>   method, but it’s rarely invoked explicitly.)

So, you must inherit `NSView` and implement `draw(_:)`

**Here is the code:**

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport


class view: NSView
{
    override init(frame: NSRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        NSColor.blue.setFill()
        NSRectFill(self.bounds)
    }
}

var v = view(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

It is better to use iOS than macOS in Playground because it is easy and also you can find a ton of tutorials or answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm also thinking to use iOS in Playground due to lack of tutorials.